# server principal not able to access database on second call

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2017. I am in the role of `sa` for the server in question. I have two databases that are used in an ETL process. The ETL is coded in one database, and the raw imported tables are located in the staging database. All ETL is handled in SQL stored procedures that follow a pattern. The first step in each ETL SP is a call to a diagnostics table in the staging database.

My current ETL job is a wrapper around two of these ETL sps; the wrapper itself contains only code that accesses the main db.
The first SP can be called and successfully selects the data from the staging db, however, the second SP that has *identical* code up to the point of failure with the first, fails on accessing the diagnostics table and tells me

> The server principal "sa" is not able to access the database "staging" under the current security context.

The problem stays if I comment out the first SP call, so something must be different in the definition of the two SPs, but I cannot spot it.
There are plenty of SPs that use the diagnostics staging table, so it is not a general problem (as stated in answers to similar questions that suggest changing security options in the staging database), but must be related to the new SP somehow.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like one/some of the stored procedures are doing `EXECUTE AS` tricks. _While the context switch to the database user is active, any attempt to access resources outside of the database will cause the statement to fail. This includes USE database statements, distributed queries, and queries that reference another database that uses three- or four-part identifiers._ Ref: [EXECUTE AS (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Execute as was indeed the Differenzen, though even more confusing - execute as owner did not work, but execute as caller did. The databases had been created on another machine, and the owner of the db was unknown in the target machine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As too often happens, I failed to recognize a subtle difference between the two stored procedures: They both call a logging stored procedure, but this logging procedure has two variants, one with prefix `sp_`, and another one with the prefix `usp`. (Someone reacted to the Microsoft warning not to use `sp_` as prefix.) The old one had an 'execute as owner' inside, which caused the error.

Replacing the function call with the new version fixed the error.

Sometimes the error is on the other side of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

There are three things to check/do.

First of all, the login associated with the user in database `DB1` must also be associated with a user in `DB2`. This provides the login with a security context in database `DB2`. The `sa` login will map to `dbo` in both databases, so this should already be fine.

Second, the security context of the code being executed in `DB1` must be "trustworthy". In other words, when the user context goes from `DB1` back up to the server level and then down into `DB2` via the cross-database call, the new user context has to trust the original login. There are two ways to do this, the quick and dirty and opens-up-possible-security-holes way, and the more complicated but safer way:

Quick and not entirely safe: `alter database DB1 set trustworthy on`.

Safe: Use [signed modules](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3336/how-to-use-module-signing-for-sql-server-security/)

Third, in the general case you should check that the owner of `DB1` and the owner of `DB2` are the same (otherwise you can't cross database ownership chain): `select owner_sid from sys.databases where name in ('DB1', 'DB2')` But as with the first point, as a sysadmin you can take ownership of anything.

Comment: thanks for the post, but I explicitly stated that the login works on one SP, but not on the other, so your answer does not exactly fit to the question

Comment: @Geep OK, when you said "The ETL is coded in one database, and the raw imported tables are located in the staging database" and "the wrapper itself contains only code that accesses the main db", it seems natural to read that to mean one of them had a cross db call that the other one did not.